# Findorfail in Laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

im probably just not thinking right but here is my problem:
Im trying to learn laravel by building a simple todo-app.

I have a model name todo.

```
> <?php
> 
> namespace App;
> 
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
> 
> class todo extends Model {
> 
> 
> 
> }
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('todo', 'pagesController@index');

Route::get('/todo/{id}','pagesController@show');
```

And my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $todo = DB::table('todo')->get();
        return view('pages.todo')->with('todo',$todo);


    }

  public function show($id)
    {
        $dos = todo::findOrFail($id);
        return ($dos);

    }
```

The index method is working.
But show() gives me a strange error.

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app2.todos' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `todos` where `todos`.`id` = 1 limit 1)**

Its strange because it always looke for TODOS and not todo which would be the right name. I cant find a TODOS anywhere in my code. I even did a search for todos. Nothing. So how does this happen?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Laravel convention. If no table name is defined in model class it assumes table name as plural form of model class name. You can override conventional table name with your own in Model class like below.

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class todo extends Model {

 protected $table = 'todo';

 }
```

By the way it is also a convention to name a class with first letter capital. So it should be `Todo`.

Answer (score 1):

todos because there is a function in Laravel to plural words during finding table names.
show method don't see todo because todo is from index method.
you should set $todo in constructor as a new TodoModel instance.
or second time in show method like in index method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your table name in the model by $table property. it's the laravel convention. otherwise laravel treat a table name of a plural form of model.

example:

if your model class name is "User". Laravel assume that your table name is 'users' if you do not define it in your model class explicitly. It's better to tell your model class which table will be effected through of this Model.

```
 <?php
     namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class User extends Model {

    //it will effect user table because you define it here otherwise laravel will assume 'users' table
     protected $table = 'user';
     }
```